# Neo4j: How do you find the first (shallowest) match for all relationship matches?

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a data set that duplicates the commit history inside a git repository. Each `Commit` node has one or more parents, which are also `Commit` nodes. Commits have a `commit_id` property and have references to the files that changed in that commit. In other words:

```
ChangedFile<-[:CHANGED_IN]-Commit
Commit-[:CONTAINS]->ChangedFile
Commit-[:CHILD_OF]->Commit
```

I'm now trying to write a Cypher query that returns commit/file pairs where each commit contains the most recent change to the file. Since the graph has been designed to mimic git history with parent/child relationships, the query should support choosing a commit to start at, i.e. the HEAD.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
MATCH
  (commit:Commit {commit_id: '460665895c91b2f9018e361b393d7e00dc86b418'}),
  (file:ChangedFile)<-[:CHANGED_IN]-commit-[:CHILD_OF*]->(parent:Commit)
RETURN
  file.path, parent.commit_id
```

Unfortunately this query returns all the commits that match at any number of levels deep within the `[:CHILD_OF*]` relationship. I want it to instead stop at the first match for each file. As things stand now, I end up seeing a bunch of duplicate file paths in the result set.

How do I tell Neo4j/Cypher to stop at the first match per file, regardless of depth? I've tried adding `UNIQUE` and a bunch of other things, but I can't seem to find something that works. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Side comment: `CONTAINS` and `CHANGED_IN` seem to be identical (aside from any possible properties). You should consider just using one of them.

Comment: Oh that's true. I'm a n00b at graph databases, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your data model and what you are after, but why are you looking for variable length paths from the commit to its parent? Aren't you just looking for the parent?

```
MATCH
  (commit:Commit {commit_id: '460665895c91b2f9018e361b393d7e00dc86b418'}),
  (file:ChangedFile)<-[:CHANGED_IN]-commit-[:CHILD_OF]->(parent:Commit)
RETURN
  file.path, parent.commit_id
```

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm looking for the commit that contains the most recent change to the file, which could be any number of parental hops away.